# Absloute maximum of enchantment levels using /give in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, what is the absolute maximum enchantment level possible in minecraft using /give or similar command. An enchantment table gives at best a level 5 enchantment for lots of levels. This will be a cool easter egg to put in resource packs.

Answer (score 3):

The maximum enchantment level possible is **32,767**, as this is the [maximum value of the 16-bit integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004944/max-value-of-integer).

Comment: You may want to take a look at the linked question again 2^31-1 is 2,147,483,647. But you are right, the maximum level is 32,767, because the level is stored in a **16-bit** short integer. (http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Player.dat_format#Enchantments hover over **lvl**).